# in exceI sheet , I want the difference of top two values(max- second max) in the column "Total" for each "PC NAME" , is there any excel formula?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

[![EXCEL SCREENSHOT ][1]][1]

for e.g. I need the difference of 562190-338101 for Aruku, and same for each PC NAME values

any help will be appreciated
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvuF0.png

Answer (score 0):

1] "Unique PC name" `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$28,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A$2:A$28),0),0)),"")
```

2] "Difference of top 2 values" `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(D2="","",SUM(AGGREGATE(14,6,B$2:B$28/(A$2:A$28=D2),{1,2})*{1,-1}))
```

[image]